# Getting an expression over a horizon for a given recursive equation in sympy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

The following example is stated just for the purpose of precise definition of the query. Consider a recursive equation x[k+1] = a*x[k] where a is some constant. Now, is there an easier way or an existing method within sympy/numpy that does the following (i.e., gives an expression over a horizon for a given recursive equation):

```
def get_expr(init, num):
  a = Symbol('a')
  expr = init
  for i in range(num):
    expr = a*expr
  return expr

x0 = Symbol('x0')
get_expr(x0,3)
```

Horizon above is 3.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest using SymPy's `rsolve` to try to find a closed form solution to your equation, but it seems that at least for this specific one, there is a bug that prevents it from working.  See http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2943.  Maybe if you really want to know for a more complicated expression you could try that.  For this one, the closed form solution is just `a**n*x0`.

Aside from that, SymPy doesn't have any functions that would do this evaluation directly, but it does have some things that can help.  There are some memoization decorators in `sympy.utilities.memoization` that are made for internal use, but should work just fine for external uses.  They can help make your evaluation more efficient by caching the result of previous evaluations.  You'll need to write the `get_expr` recursively for it to work effectively.  Or you could just write your own cacher.  It's not that complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions asmeurer.